# Animating divs inside 100% width container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck with this issue. I have 5 columns of divs floating next to each other. When hovering on it, the div which is hovered should extend its width via animation. I covered that part so far but my problem is when I hover that div, the last div appears at the bottom (meaning it exceeds 100% width container) I am not sure how to solve this without preventing to exceed 100% container.

Here s what I have done so far:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71px23q0/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxWidth = $(".box").width();
  $(".box").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: "30%"
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: boxWidth
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="background:red"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:grey"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:yellow"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:green"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:#000000"></div>
```

Comment: The sum of your div is 100%, but have you tried to reduce it? Maybe you have padding/margin and so the sum is greater than 100%. Try to view them with a developer tool (press f12 in Firefox or Google Chrome)

Answer (score 4):

If you like [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex), than do it this way:

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    transition: flex-grow .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
    flex-grow: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:grey"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:#000000"></div>
</div>
```

A nice guide for flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Same code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s92xe6wx/).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the width of one div to 30% the other divs need to shrink to 17.5% (70% / 4) width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
 background:black;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.wrap .box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  transition:width .25s ease;
}

.wrap:hover .box:hover {
  width: 30%;
}
.wrap:hover .box {
  width: 17.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:grey"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background:#000000"></div>
</div>
```